# "401 unauthorised issue occur " when create customer using REST API call in Quickbook online

Tags: quickbooks-online

POST Call

```
URL:https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/[companyid]/customer
```

Headers:

```
Content-Type
application/json
```

Authorization

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="**",oauth_token="***",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1475665481",oauth_nonce="EUzCNk",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="**"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A `401` error occurs in either of two scenarios:

1. You didn't sign your OAuth request correctly
2. You're using the wrong OAuth tokens/consumer secret/consumer key

Check your tokens.

Check your signing.

If you have more questions, POST YOUR CODE and POST THE RAW REQUEST AND RAW RESPONSE so we can actually help you.